# A question about different pairs that are formed from a set of 16 different poeple such that...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I got the following problem:

---

Given a set of 16 **different** people.

We **partition** the people  into **pairs of two**.

Each pair needs to accomplish a task.

And the probability that a pair accomplishes the task is $0.8$.

(1) Find the variance of the discrete random variable $X$ that denotes the number of **pairs** that accomplished the task.

(2) Find the variance of the discrete random variable $Y$ that denotes the number of **people** that accomplished the task.

(3) If before the start of the mission, each pair is given a $100\$$ and if the pair accomplishes the task than the pair get an additional $100\$$, if the pair fails to accomplish the task than the pair pays $50\$$ from the amount given (the $100\$$ given at the start of the task).

Find the variance of the discrete random variable $Z$ that denotes the **total** amount of money the 8 pairs hold at the end of the task.

---

My answer for (1) is:

Since each pair has probability of $0.8$ to accomplish the task and since the are $8$ pairs, we get that $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $(8,0.8)$ (I.e. $X$~$B(8,0.8)$) and so the variance of $X$ is:

$Var(X)= 8\times 0.8\times (1-0.8)=1.28$

(Please correct me if I wrong)

But in the case of (2) and (3), I got stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks on any help.

Comment: Hint for (b): $Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(X)$ whare $a$ and $b$ are constants

Comment: Your answer on (1) is correct. The hint of @Henry can also be used for (3). Just write $Y$ and $Z$ as linear forms $aX+b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for (2):

Notice that $Y=2X$ and so $Var(Y)=Var(2X)=2^2Var(X)=4\times 1.28=5.12$

Answer for (3):

Notice that $Z=100\times 8 + 100\times X -50\times(8-X) = 150X+400$ and so           $Var(Z)=Var(150X+400)=150^2Var(X)= 150^2\times 1.28=28800$